# Selenium-RC Unable to handle Confirmation box

Tags: c#, nunit, selenium, selenium-rc

I am testing a web app where i delete an item from a list. Upon clicking on delete, the app asks for confirmation. Selenium IDE detects it as a confirmation box. When I run the code thro' the RC (C#), it even catches the confirmation-box, executes the click of delete button on that confirmation box, but, the confirmation box is never visible on the screen. Further, it only clicks on the delete button; the item doesn't get deleted. I tried it manually, works fine.

Please help, I'm new to Selenium and tried to find the answers at multiple forums without any success.

Here's the code:

```
string confirmation;
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
    if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
    try
    {
        confirmation=selenium.GetConfirmation();

        if ((confirmation == " Delete confirmation message")) break;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        PrintLog("Error while waiting for confirmation. Error: "+e.Message);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}           

try
{
    Assert.IsTrue(confirmation == "Delete confirmation message");
}
catch (AssertionException e)
{
    PrintLog(e.Message);
}

selenium.FireEvent("//a[@id='btnOkConfirm']","click");
```

After the last statement, the selected item must get deleted and page should refresh, but, nothing happens. All I can see is "Javascript:;" written in the status bar of the firefox window. I guess its problematic to get javascript hrefs working in selenium-rc.
Thanks,
Vamyip

Comment: To be more specific, I am unable to get the click on the delete button of confirmation box working.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lately, I've discovered that this behavior is occurring due to the architecture of selenium(more precisely, its javascript based core). when I do the test manually, keeping the selenium IDE open, this behavior is replicated. So, I think there's no immediate solution to this problem right now. Will post here if I find a workaround.

Thanks to Dave for replying.

---

Update: The development team informed me that a javascript function is not being called with selenium IDE running alongside. This indeed is a problem with Selenium's Javascript core.

### Thanks to everybody who took time to respond to this question.

Regards,
Vamyip

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of commands to deal with JavaScript confirmations. Selenium will by default choose 'OK' at a confirmation, unless you send the `chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation` command. In order to consume the confirmation you will need to use the `getConfirmation` command.

Selenium reference for above commands:

- http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#storeConfirmation
- http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation
- http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#chooseOkOnNextConfirmation

Additionally, if your `click` command is not showing the JavaScript confirmation you might find that the appropriate event is not being fired. You could try using the `mouseDown` and `mouseUp`commands, or the `fireEvent` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will check and inform you whether successful ASAP.
 Thanks again - Vamyip

Comment: I've answered my post. Could you please confirm whether it is true. Thanks